# ngIf doesn't display the intended output

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework, angular-ng-if

I'm having a problem with hiding the content from the user. for example, from top 1 to 3, the user's top 1 is visual and top 2 is verbal. It should display the content for both visual and verbal but will hide the second part.

If from top 1 to 3, I only got verbal but no visual, it will display the 2nd part and hides the first part. What am I doing wrong?

```
 //Hides content if user is Both visual and verbal
 <div *ngFor="let styleElement of styles">
  <ion-slides *ngIf="styleElement.first == 'Visual' || styleElement.second == 'Visual' || styleElement.third == 'Visual' ||

        styleElement.first == 'Visual' && styleElement.second == 'Verbal' ||
        styleElement.first == 'Visual' && styleElement.third == 'Verbal' ||
        styleElement.second == 'Visual' && styleElement.first == 'Verbal' ||

        styleElement.second == 'Visual' && styleElement.third == 'Verbal' ||
        styleElement.third == 'Visual' && styleElement.first == 'Verbal' ||
        styleElement.third == 'Visual' && styleElement.second == 'Verbal'
        ">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of universeSlides">
      <br>
      <img [src]="slide.image" class="slide-image" />
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</div>


 //Hides this if user is only verbal
// the 2nd part im referring to
<div *ngFor="let styleElement of styles">
  <div *ngIf="
  styleElement.first != 'Visual' && styleElement.first != 'Verbal' ||
  styleElement.first != 'Visual' && styleElement.second != 'Verbal' ||
  styleElement.first != 'Visual' && styleElement.third != 'Verbal'
    ">
.....
```

Comment: Have you tried console logging to make sure everything comes out as expected?  Also you could try wrapping some of the conditionals in parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<div
      *ngIf="((styleElement.first != 'Visual' && styleElement.first != 'Verbal')
       || (styleElement.first != 'Visual' && styleElement.second != 'Verbal')
       || (styleElement.first != 'Visual' && styleElement.third != 'Verbal'))"
    >
```

Comment: Please see edited question. I have refixed my scenario. thanks

Comment: @AngularNewbie, please return your question to it's original state, and if RaviTeja answered your original question, select it. If you have a new question, please post it as a separate question, At the very least, post all your updates under a block of text reading `-----UPDATE-----`